# Recursively find all parents and children in self-joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, self-join

I have a table called `OrganisationTrees` which self joins. 
Parents are called `parent_tree`; children are called `sub_trees`. I need to input a single OrganisationTree and then find all of its sub_trees and then all of its sub_trees etc. until all children are exhausted.

My current code is

```
class OrganisationTree < ActiveRecord::Base

  ####other code here###

  def map_sub_trees(list=[])        
    unit = []
    sub_unit = []
    parent = "parent - #{self.name}"
    unit << parent
    self.sub_trees.each do |tree|
      sub_unit<<tree.name
      if tree.sub_trees.count >= 1
        tree.map_sub_trees(list)
      end
    end
    unit << sub_unit
    list << unit
    puts list.reverse.inspect
  end
```

And current output looks like this:

```
[["parent - Tree 1", ["Tree 2", "Tree 4", "Tree 5"]], ["parent - Tree 2", ["Tree 3"]], ["parent - Tree 3", ["Tree 6"]]]
nil
```

My problem is that I can't seem to get the arrays to nest properly. For example, the array starting `parent - Tree 2` should be nested inside array starting `parent - Tree 1` as its first element as `Tree 2` is the first child of `Tree 1.`

If it makes life simpler, output could take any form e.g hash

Comment: did you get answer?